# Scala anonymous mixin?

Tags: scala, traits, mixins

when debugging I had to inspect the **scala.collection.GenSetLike** file. I encountered this little bit of code in the interface:

```
trait GenSetLike[A, +Repr] 
extends GenIterableLike[A, Repr]
  with (A => Boolean)
  with Equals
  with Parallelizable[A, parallel.ParSet[A]] {
  ...
}
```

What does this `(A => Boolean)` mix means? I tried searching with various keywords but could not find something satisfactory.
This syntax indicated *a function that takes an A and returns a Boolean*, but I can't see the meaning in the trait mixin context...

My first guess was that is related to stuff like *constructor* or `apply`, but this is just an intuition.

Please teach me!

Comment: It's the same as `... with Function1[A, Boolean] ...`. Also note that user-defined binary type constructors can also be used in infix notation, for example `trait <=[A, B] { def invert(b: B): A }; trait Foo[X, Y] extends (X <= Y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` in Scala implements `Function1[A, Boolean]` (`A => Boolean`) interface  overriding `apply` to be same as `contains`, so sets in Scala can be used as functions.

```
> val s = Set(1,2,3) 
s: Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

> s(2) 
res1: Boolean = true

> s.apply(3) 
res2: Boolean = true

> s(23) 
res3: Boolean = false
```

This is, btw, the reason why Set is invariant.

Answer (score 1):

`A => Boolean` is the syntactic sugar for `Function1` trait

## Scala REPL

```
scala> def f[A] = (a: A) => true
f: [A]=> A => Boolean
```

The above lambda can also be written as

```
scala> def f[A]: Function1[A, Boolean] = (a: A) => true
f: [A]=> A => Boolean
```